# Flutter : How to navigate to new page after state change?

Tags: widget, dart, page-lifecycle, flutter

How to navigate to new page after state change?

I had an app that require login first. Only after login, the app component are fully created. So I wrote something like this:

Main app

```
class AppComponentState extends State<AppComponent> implements CredentialProvider {

  Credential credential;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (credential == null) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(this),
        },
      );
    } else {
      return new MaterialApp(
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/': (BuildContext context) => new Desktop(credential),
          ...
        },
      );
    }
  }
  @override
  void setCredential(Credential s) {
    setState(() {
      credential = s;
    });
  }
}
```

Credential provider interface

```
abstract CredentialProvider {
    void setCredential(Credential c);
}
```

The login button listener in `LoginPage`, credential is set and route to the new page.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  void _handleSubmitted() {
    ...
    credentialProvider.setCredential(c); // this change main widget state and hence new pages are created
    // call setTimeout ?
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"); // this should go to new page, because credential is set.
  }

  ...
}
```

It seem like, I have to wait current [digest loop](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) to finish before invoking `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/");`. Is there any good way to do in flutter digest cycle like `setTimeout` in javascript?

It is a bit weird, conditional creation of `MaterialApp`. Is there better pattern in flutter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your direct question, [`addPostFrameCallback`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) or [`Future.delayed`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) can call code after a minimal delay. However, there are some issues with this pattern:

- I would recommend that you only have one `MaterialApp` widget. You can have a separate route for the login page.
- In Flutter, state flows from parent to child. Children should not be calling methods on parent `State`. Instead the parent can pass callbacks to the children. Or perhaps a [`ChangeNotifier`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html). If there's no other way to do what you want, you could use a [`GlobalKey`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) to get access to the `AppComponentState` from any place in the app and call `setCredential` on it, but you're losing some encapsulation and testability by doing so.
- Pushing another `"/"` on the navigator stack might cause issues if the user presses the back button and goes back to the previous place. Probably what you want is to trigger a rebuild of some widget that is a parent of `LoginPage` and `Desktop`. Or you can call `runApp()` again to force *everything* to rebuild.

Comment: `onGenerateRoute` could be a solution to solve multiple `MaterialApp`?
 It has its own [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728153/flutter-do-i-need-to-cache-widget-in-ongenerateroute) though?